# Does children template inherit settings from parent template?

Tags: symfony, twig

In my parent twig I have set the default translation domain

```
// parent twig
{% trans_default_domain 'domain' %}
```

The children templates doesn't seem to inherit this it always defaults to `messages`

How do I set the `trans_default_domain` from the parent template and use that setting in all the children templates?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/9822 :

> `trans_default_domain` only affects the current template. It does not
>   affect other templates (it would be really hard to make it impact the
>   parent template, as itis resolved at compilation time currently and
>   the compilation of the parent cannot depend on the child). It could
>   also become really confusing to have the default domain changing based
>   on stuff outside the template (and become really hard to debug)

To realize that:

> Make the parent template use a variable in its default domain, so that
>   you can modify the variable value in the child